# Kafka Consumer giving only first produced message

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka. I am using Kafka 0.9.0.0 client for java. While consuming the data from a particular topic, I am getting same message every time (Which was posted for the first time ), when I start the producer-consumer java project.

My Requirement is to produce some message and consume it and check if both the messages are same or not.

Below is the code I am using for Kafka Consumer:-

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> newConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);
newConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(props.getProperty("monitoring.topic")));

String consumerRecord = "";
ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = newConsumer.poll(120000);

for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : consumerRecords) {
    logger.info("Found message  for  {} {} {}", adapter, record.key(), record.value());
    System.out.println("consumerMessage : " + record.value());
    JSONObject jsonConsumerMessage = (JSONObject) (parser.parse(record.value()));

    Long offset = record.offset();
    System.out.println("Offset of this record is " + offset);
    String UUIDProducer = message.get("UUID").toString();

    String UUIDConsumer = jsonConsumerMessage.get("UUID").toString();
    System.out.println("UUIDProducer :  " + UUIDProducer);
    System.out.println("UUIDConsumer :  " + UUIDConsumer);
    if (UUIDProducer.equals(UUIDConsumer)) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Note: -I am able to consume the latest messages through command line.

Can anyone please guide me on this ?

Comment: Any chance your properties have `auto.commit.enable=false`?

Comment: No It doesn't have and i have tried below configuration as well:- 
`props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");`

Comment: Did you set the `group.id` property?

Comment: Below are the Kafka configs:- 

`kafkaProp.setProperty("bootstrap.servers",prop.getProperty("bootstrap.servers"));
   kafkaProp.setProperty("group.id",prop.getProperty("group.id"));
   kafkaProp.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
kafkaProp.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "20000");  
kafkaProp.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
kafkaProp.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");`

Comment: Assuming that `prop.getProperty("group.id")` always returns the same, valid value, then the the only thing I can think of is to try and commit offset `consumer.commitOffsets(true)` after fetching. Since I'm assuming your consumer quits after this code, it might be that automatic commit doesn't kick off in time.

Comment: I got the issue. It was my silly mistake that I m returning the true and false inside for loop. Its causing the loop to come out as soon as first message came from the topic.

By the way thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my silly mistake that I am returning the true and false value inside for loop. Its causing the loop to come out as soon as first message came from the topic.